# Стиль коммитов в Git

Tags: git

Есть ли общепринятый стиль именования коммитов? Если нет, какое именование является хорошим тоном?

Comment: вы говорите про комментарии к commit?

Comment: Хорошим тоном является **консистентное** содержимое сообщений к коммитам.

Comment: Т.е. все сообщения в одном стиле - например, все начинаются с номера задачи в таск-трекере. И т.п.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Про многие моменты разработки есть очень много информации. Как писать комментарии, как именовать классы, методы, какие паттерны использовать и т.д. и т.п. Но есть одна область, в которой многие даже и не задумываются о том, что можно что-то улучшить — это написание коммитов.

Зачем это вообще нужно? Чтобы экономить время и нервы, не больше и не меньше. Это мы еще обсудим чуть позже, а пока рассмотрим как же вообще именуются коммиты.

**Общий стиль**

Если пройтись по тем же коммитам с GitHub, то можно увидеть довольно обширное количество вариантов написания коммитов. Основные рекомендации по написанию можно выделить такие:

**Что сделать + для какой сущности + подробности (необязательно)**

Старайтесь найти единый стиль для коммитов и придерживаться его. Для себя я нашел удобным такой стиль, когда я сначала указываю что я делаю. Например, add. После этого я указываю что-то, над чем я произвожу действие. Например, ui-bootstrap.js dependency. В большинстве случаев такой записи более чем достаточно. Если есть еще какая-то пояснительная надпись, то ее лучше вынести в отдельную большую запись, о чем мы еще поговорим. Если запись маленькая, но очень нужная, то можно дописать её прямо к коммиту. Но лучше еще раз задуматься, действительно ли нужна эта надпись, или она будет привлекать ненужное внимание.

Бывает так:

```
dependency for managing ui-bootstrap.js components was added here on 18.06.2013 by olegafx
```

Но лучше:

```
add ui-bootstrap.js dependency
```

**Большие сообщения в коммите**

Так что же делать с большими сообщениями? Конечно, писать. Например, это может быть важная информация с сообщением, что ваш коммит ломает предыдущую функциональность, заменяя её очень крутой и простой новой. Такое бывает даже в самых крупных проектах, поэтому очень важно рассказать людям как сделать так, чтобы всё заработало вновь.

Проще всего добавить пустую строку под основным сообщением коммита и начать вводить информацию уже там. Кстати, здесь уже можно писать глаголы в прошедшем времени, если очень хочется. Например:

```
replace twitter-bootstrap.css with pure.css

Made UI much cleaner.

BREAKING CHANGE. You need to use new class-names for grid-related elements.
```

**Пишем сообщение с маленькой буквы**

Нет никакого особого смысла писать первое слово с большой буквы. С маленькой читается гораздо проще.

Бывает так:

```
Add ui-bootstrap.js dependency
ADD ui-bootstrap.js dependency
```

Но лучше:

```
add ui-bootstrap.js dependency
```

**НЕ используем прошедшее время**

Чем проще, тем лучше. Прошедшее время слишком усложняет чтение сообщений. Предстаьте, что вы обращаетесь к Git: «Git, добавь», «Git, удали» и т.д.

Бывает так:

```
added ui-bootstrap.js dependency
```

Но лучше:

```
add ui-bootstrap.js dependency
```

**Убираем лишние знаки препинания**

Например, зачем вам точка в конце сообщения? Итак понятно, что оно закончено. То же самое относится к точке с запятой.

Бывает так:

```
add ui-bootstrap.js dependency;
```

Но лучше:

```
add ui-bootstrap.js dependency
```

**Русский язык**

Нет ничего постыдного в том, чтобы использовать русский язык в коммитах. Но делать это нужно только в том случае, если вы на 1000% уверены, что данный код будет интересен только русскоязычным людям. Например, у вас есть скрипт для VK, который указывает на карте всех фанатов Стаса Михайлова. Очевидно, что это будет мало кому интересно среди зарубежных граждан. Да и для россиян тоже, если честно.

**Причесываем коммиты перед отправкой**

Все коммиты в локальном репозитории можно именовать как угодно. Если вам проще запомнить, что «temp commit 1» — это первая рабочая версия какой-то функциональности, а «temp commit 2» — это ее исправленная и отрефакторенная версия, то пожалуйста, никто особо вас ругать не будет. Но. Огроменное НО. Перед отправкой приведите, пожалуйста, свои коммиты в самый лучший вид. Для большинства случаев подойдет замечательная команда:

```
git rebase -i
```

С помощью нее можно расставить коммиты в правильном порядке, объединить их, переименовать в соответствии со всеми правилами хорошего тона. Очень мощная и полезная команда, но не переусердствуйте, а то код финальной версии какой-то новой функциональности можно перекрыть кодом самой первой глючной версии. Ну и если вы уже отправили свой код в удаленный репозиторий, то rebase лучше не использовать, а то получится только хуже.

**Находим свой любимый стиль**

Я нашел такой в проекте AngularJS. У них есть даже отдельный [документ](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QrDFcIiPjSLDn3EL15IJygNPiHORgU1_OOAqWjiDU5Y), посвященный оформлению коммитов. Все моменты, о которых я рассказал выше, есть в этом документе. И это прекрасно. Потому что мне приходилось искать эти моменты самому из разных источников, своего опыта, а здесь все лежит уже в одном месте и написано хорошим простым языком. Кратко рассмотрим основные моменты.

**Указываем тип коммита**

Есть несколько заранее определенных типов:

- feature — используется при добавлении новой функциональности уровня приложения
- fix — если исправили какую-то серьезную багу
- docs — всё, что касается документации
- style — исправляем опечатки, исправляем форматирование
- refactor — рефакторинг кода приложения
- test — всё, что связано с тестированием
- chore — обычное обслуживание кода

Не всегда эти типы можно легко различить при написании приложения (например, refactor и chore), поэтому можно придумать свои.

**Указываем область действия (scope)**

Сразу после типа коммита без всяких пробелов указываем в скобках область, на которую распространяется наш коммит. После этого пишем наш стандартный коммит.

Например, может быть область видимости модуля:

```
refactor(audio-controls) use common library for all controls
```

Или область видимости файла:

```
chore(Gruntfile.js) add watch task
```

**Для чего всё это**

Как я уже говорил в самом начале статьи, для сохранения времени и нервов! Путём упрощения следующих операций:

- Автоматическая генерация списка изменений (CHANGELOG.md и подобные). Даже если он не сформируется полностью, то будет хотя бы какя-то отправная точка для внесения небольших поправок.
- Игнорирование неподходящих коммитов при поиске места, где все сломалось (например, с помощью git bisect).Коммиты, улучшающие документацию, тесты, стиль кода и т.д. могут сразу быть пропущены. Если у вас сломался модуль audio-controls, то вы будете смотреть только те сообщения, где в scope указан данный модуль.
- Просто более насыщенная и понятная история развития проекта.

<sub>Источник: [Стиль именования коммитов](https://habrahabr.ru/post/183646/)</sub>

Comment: Как сообщество относится к полному копипасту этой статьи? https://habrahabr.ru/post/183646/

Comment: Много спорных вещей. Комменты к источнику это подтверждают.

Comment: Вдобавок к вопросу @ZhukovRoman: как сообщество относится к вопросам, ответ на которые легко нагуглить?

Answer (score 1):

1.1 Коммиты должны быть атомарными и НЕБОЛЬШИМИ, т.е. одна логическая правка - один коммит.
    Все рефакторинги, переименования и пр. параллельные усовершенствования лучше оформлять отдельным коммитом.
    Ориентироваться надо на других разработчиков, которые будут просматривать эти коммиты.

1.2 Все форматирование кода, приведение к стандарту оформлять ОТДЕЛЬНЫМ коммитом.

1.3 Каждую миграцию структуры БД или редактирование миграции оформлять ОТДЕЛЬНЫМ коммитом.
    Чтобы иметь возможность объединить несколько коммитов по одной миграции.

1.4 Для Git принято соглашение в первой строке сообщения писать краткое описание,
    а ЧЕРЕЗ строку - подробное. Т.е. как почтовое сообщение - заголовок и тело.
    В заголовок комментария надо обязательно включать номер тикета,
    к которому он относится.
    Например:

```
----------------------
Resolves/Closes/Fixes PROJECT-1: Ошибка при добавлении периодической операции

После добавления операции выдаётся ошибка что незаполнена категория,
но при этом не даёт изменить её. Была проблема в формировании ответа
json на сервере.
----------------------
```

Такой стиль поддерживается многими task/bug tracking системами при интеграции. Таска линкуется с коммитами. Например в Jira есть такая возможность.